# Deleting superfluous points in matplotlib.path by using path.cleaned

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-cleaning

I am trying to simplify an instance of `matplotlib.path.Path` by using [`Path.cleaned`](https://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path.cleaned), i.e. I want to remove points that do not contribute to the shape of the path (as stated in the doc to [`Path.iter_segments`](https://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path.iter_segments)).
I wrote a small example below which has a point at `[0, 0.5]` that gets removed, but instead another point gets generated! I also found an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8775) addressing this problem, especially [this comment](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/8776#issuecomment-310930127).

The points before were `[[0, 0], [0, 0.5], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0]]`, the points after cleaning are `[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 0]]` with the second and third to last points being identical.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

verts = [[0, 0], [0, 0.5], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0]]
codes = [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0]  # use 79 instead of 0 for correctly drawn path border

path = Path(verts, codes)
path.should_simplify = True
cleaned_path = path.cleaned(simplify=True)

patch = mpatches.PathPatch(cleaned_path)
plt.plot(np.asarray(verts)[:, 0], np.asarray(verts)[:, 1], "rx")

ax.add_patch(patch)
plt.show()
```

How can I fix this? Btw, I am using the latest matplotlib version (2.1.2).

Comment: When running your code, only three of the edges of your rectangle are black -- is that intended behaviour?

Comment: @ThomasKühn When I use `79` instead of `0` as value for ``codes[-1]`` it will draw the box. I never really got the difference between using either of the two values, but now I will continue to use ``79`` which corresponds to ``Path.CLOSEPOLY``.

Comment: I personally would use `Path.LINETO` (=2) as that feels most logical, but according to the documentation, `Path.CLOSEPOLY` (=79) should have the same effect, as in this case the vertex is ignored. At least for me those two give the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the github issue, I'm not quite sure if this solves your problem and in which version the mentioned fix should be included. In the mean time, how about removing the duplicates yourself:

```
new_verts = []
new_codes = []
for vert, code in cleaned_path.iter_segments():
    if not new_verts or (np.any(vert != new_verts[-1]) or code != new_codes[-1]):
        new_verts.append(vert)
        new_codes.append(code)

new_path = Path(new_verts, new_codes)

print(new_path.vertices)
```

This outputs:

```
[[0. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]
```

Comment: Nice workaround! Still, an actual fix (or at least a reason for the cause of this behaviour) would be good.